# C++ equivalent of Python properties

Tags: c++, python, properties

Is there an equivalent of Python properties in C++? Or would it just be better to do this using getters and setters?

Comment: i'm commenting, because i'm not sure about it... i think you can emulate the property of python within a c++ mock template class, used to restrict the implementation (lol bad typo here before edit, sorry!). you use that template to force types, so that it will return a compiler error if used in the wrong way. something like this should recreate the python's property :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, explicit getter and setters would be the closest construct in C++.

Answer (score 17):

In C++ you're either calling a member function, or you're accessing a data member. Python properties are essentially a way of doing the former using the syntax of the latter and there's no sensible way to do that in C++.

In theory you could hack together something with a macro, `#define looks_like_data really_a_function()` but it wouldn't be pretty. Or sensible. The only necessary reason to make a function look like data is to maintain compatibility with old calling code back from when it used to be data. But in C++ this won't give you binary compatibility, and it doesn't even really give you source compatibility given that the macro will break calling code that already uses the name `looks_like_data` for something else in another context. So there's not a lot of point.

Another thing you could do is to create an actual data member that acts as a proxy for the "logical" type of the data:

```
struct Proxy {
    Foo *foo;
    Proxy(Foo *foo) : foo(foo) { }
    operator int() const {
        // getter code goes here,
        // use (const Foo*)foo rather than foo
    }
    Proxy &operator=(int a) {
       // setter code goes here
    }
    // optionally also implement boilerplate +=, -=, etc.
};

struct Foo {
    // optionally 
    // friend class Proxy;
    Proxy looks_like_data;
    Foo() : looks_like_data(this) { }
};
```

This is almost, but not quite, sensible. Using an implicit conversion *still* breaks source compatibility, because there's a rule that there can only be one user-defined implicit conversion in a chain, so if a caller has written code back when `looks_like_data` really was an `int`, and their code implicitly converts that `int` to `Bar`, then once `looks_like_data` becomes a `Proxy` it will no longer implicitly convert to `Bar` and you've broken their code anyway.

So after all that, you're best using getter/setter functions if your class really needs something that looks like a read/write property.

Answer (score 7):

There are no properties in standard C++. However, if you're developing on the Microsoft platform you could use their language extension:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx